# how to draw a route between multiple markers in google maps from mysql data base

Tags: javascript, maps

Here is my Code:

```
my.routes.r0 = new Route([

    [LatLng[0].latitude, LatLng[0].longitude],
    [LatLng[8].latitude, LatLng[8].longitude],
    [45.5096975, -73.569376]


    ]).drawRoute(my.maps.map1);
```

Please suggest a way.

Comment: how can i replace  [LatLng[0].latitude, LatLng[0].longitude],
    [LatLng[8].latitude, LatLng[8].longitude], with data from data base.

Comment: Question is too broad. We don't know what database system you're using, how you're interfacing with it, what web server you're using, etc. Your question is basically asking "how do I get data from a database into my front end", which has many, many different answers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so]. Please note that [comments are temporary and could be deleted anytime](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have additional information to provide or clarifications to make, please update your question by clicking on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/204869) for details. Thank you.

Comment: the table LatLng got data from mysql data base,  in data base i got serial number of device, latitude and longitude. i would like for each device to draw route for each device.